# Handle MediaCodec video with dropped frames

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm currently doing fast precise seeking using `MediaCodec`. What I currently do to skip frame by frame is, I first get the total frames:

```
mediaInfo.totalFrames = videoTrack.getSamples().size();
```

Then I get the length of the video file:

```
mediaInfo.durationUs = videoTrack.getDuration() * 1000 *1000 / timeScale;

//then calling:
public long getDuration() {
    if (mMediaInfo != null) {
        return (int) mMediaInfo.durationUs / 1000; // to millisecond
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Now, when I want to get the next frame I call the following:

```
mNextFrame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int frames = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(getTotalFrames));
            int intervals = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mPlayer.getDuration() / frames));

            if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mPlayer.pause();
                mPlayer.seekTo(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() + intervals);
            } else {
                mPlayer.seekTo(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() + intervals);
            }
           
        }
    });
```

Here is the info about the file I'm testing with:

`Frames = 466`
`Duration = 15523`

So the interval between frames are

`33,311158798283262`

In other words, each time I press the next button the intervals will be rounded to `33`, when I press the next button it will call `mPlayer.seekTo(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() + 33` meaning that some frames will be lost, or that is what I thought. I tested and got the following back when logging `getCurrentPosition` after each time the button is pressed and here is the result:

`33 -> 66 -> 99 -> 132 -> 166`

Going from `132` to `166` is 34ms instead of 33, so there was a compensation to make up with the frames that would have be lost.

---

**The above works perfectly fine, I can skip through frames without any problem, here is the issue I facing.**

Taking the same logic I used above I created a custom `RangeBar`. I created a method `setTickCount` (it's basically the same as `seekbar.setMax`) and I set the "TickCount" like this:

```
int frames = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(getTotalFrames));
mrange_bar.setTickCount(frames);
```

So the max value of my `RangeBar` is the amout of frames in the video.

When the "Tick" value changes I call the following:

```
int frames = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(getTotalFrames));
int intervals = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mPlayer.getDuration() / frames));
mPlayer.seekTo(intervals * TickPosition);
```

So the above will work like this, if my tickCount position is, let's say 40:

`mPlayer.seekTo(33 * 40);  //1320ms`

I would think that the above would work fine because I used the exact same logic, but instead the video "jump/skip" back to (what I assume is the key frame) and the continues the seeking.

Why is happening and how I can resolve this issue?

---

### EDIT 1:

I mentioned above that it is jumping to the previous key frame, but I had a look again and it is calling end of stream while seeking (at spesific points during the video). When I reach end of stream I release my previous buffer so that one frame can still be displayed to avoid a black screen, by calling:

`mDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(prevBufferIndex, true);`

So, for some reason, end of stream is called, where I then restart mediacodec causing a "lag/jump" effect.
If I remove the above, I don't get the frame "jump", but there is still a lag while mediacodec is being initialized.

---

### EDIT 2:

After digging deeper I found that `readSampleData` is -1:

```
ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mDecoder.getInputBuffers();
    int inIndex = mDecoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
    if (inIndex >= 0) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = inputBuffers[inIndex];
        int sampleSize = mExtractor.readSampleData(buffer, 0);
        if (sampleSize < 0) {
            mDecoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
            mIsExtractorReachedEOS = true;
        } else {
            mDecoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, sampleSize, mExtractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
            mExtractor.advance();
        }
    }
```

For some reason my `sampleSize` is -1 at a specific point during seeking.

---

### EDIT 3

This issue is definitely regarding the time that I pass, I tried 2 different approaches, the first:

```
mPlayer.seekTo(progress);

//position is retrieved by setting mSeekBar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration); ....
```

and the second approach, I determine the frame intervals:

```
//Total amount of frames in video
long TotalFramesInVideo = videoTrack.getSamples().size();
//Duration of file in milliseconds
int DurationOfVideoInMs = mPlayer.getDuration();

//Determine interval between frames
int frameIntervals = DurationOfVideoInMs / Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(TotalFramesInVideo));

//Then I seek to the frames like this:
mPlayer.seekTo(position * frameIntervals);
```

After trying both the above methods, I realised that the issue is related to the time being passed to mediaCodec because the "lag/jump" happens at different places.

I'm not sure why this doesn't happen when I call:

```
mPlayer.seekTo(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() + intervals);
```

Comment: So what have you achieve now and your latest problem?  Correct if I'm wrong, your problem is you have a seekbar(rangebar) for you to forward/rewind.  However, after you seek to a certain time, it goes to that seek time but go back to previous after?

Comment: @AngusTay I think I've managed to resolve the issue, I'm busy testing it now.

Comment: Cool! Keep it up

Comment: What are the values of `mPlayer.seekTo(intervals * TickPosition);` in the bad situation? And what goes exactly wrong when seeking? It's a bit vague to me.

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen `intervals` are the duration of the video devided by the amout of frames and `TickPosition` is the frame where I'm currently at (see the question for a better explanation). The problem was that end of stream was being called when reaching a certain point in the video while seeking. I found that I was giving the wrong presentation time. I called `presentationTime x 0.5` then using that to check if current frame is the target frame and if it's not I break my loop causing end of stream to be called. After removing `x 0.5` the issue is resolved.

Comment: So your issue is resolved? If so, please put your own answer below and accept it to let other people know the issue is resolved.